# why console.log get different results if pass different parameters?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

demo.js:

```
let obj = { foo: "bar\"bar" }
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))        // it will get: {"foo":"bar\"bar"}
console.log(999, JSON.stringify(obj))   // it will get: 999 '{"foo":"bar\\"bar"}'
```

and then run:

> node demo.js

why the two lines get different results?

Comment: I am sorry there were so many typoes. Now I have edited it. Please read it again.

Comment: I am unable to repo your issue. Tried on both mac and windows. Tried from both a node REPL and from a file called `demo.js`. https://imgur.com/bEAy9mx  What OS? What version of node? What shell?

Comment: @ErtySeidohl - both node and chrome output the **former** for me!!

Comment: I am very very sorry, I edited it again....

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found if you look at [this documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args). All the arguments are passed to `util.format()`, which returns a concatenation of all the given arguments if the first argument is not a string.

It first converts each argument to a string representation using `util.inspect()` before concatenating them. This explains why both lines return different results.